# WP-Cufon adding extra space in my paragraphs in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: plugins, javascript

I'm using WP-Cufon for font replacements. It's adding extra cufon canvas out side of `p` tags in my page, which is seriously messing up my layout. The URl is this: `http://doscasas.com.mx/dev/`. But it shows alright in IE!!! Why is it happening? How can I solve it? I'm having same kind of problem with all-in-one cufon plugin too.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is more a *Cufon* problem than a *Wordpress* one, you should check out the documentation and support at [Cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/).

Comment: Thanks. I posted in cufon forum and in wordpress support too. I asked it her because I used all-in-one cfon before in another site, and although it had some problem with IE, this kind of problem didn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

I used to use cufon until I found a better way of dealing with custom fonts. This issue you are having is a cufon problem not WordPress.

I'd look at using @font-face in CSS instead of replacement techniques. [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) is a good place to get fonts to use on your site and has a generator tool to make all the css code and different font formats for you.

Unfortunately this isn't a WP plugin but shouldn't be too hard to get this into your theme.

Comment: Hope you don't mind the edit.

Comment: @kaiser - I cannot see what has changed... from the history it looks like the link was removed but its still there...

Comment: I just exchanged the "`[`" & "`(`" so the link works.